# Is it possible to get amazon ec2 instances to hibernate?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hibernation

I've tried hibernating instances on amazon ec2. You get the shutdown signal in Linux, but the aws instance doesn't get stopped, and after a hard reboot it then refuses to boot. The only way out is to terminate the instance, as far as I can tell.

Is there a technical reason why this shouldn't work?